# how to prove two groups are NOT isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation

I have two groups defined by presentations
$$\langle x, y \mid x^p = y^q       \rangle$$
$$\langle x, y \mid x^{p'} = y^{q'} \rangle$$
where $p,q,p',q'$ are all integers greater then $1$, and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$, $\gcd(p',q')=1$.

I'm not 100% sure, but i think they are not isomorphic. But I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, certainly they're isomorphic if $p = p', q = q'$, at least

Comment: Presumably you mean, assuming $(p,q)\neq (p',q')$ and $(p,q)\neq (q',p')$

Comment: There are no elements of finite order in these groups, I believe. @IsaacBrowne

Comment: Note that we have exactly two epimorphisms $G\to\Bbb Z$, given by $x\mapsto q$, $y\mapsto p$ and by $x\mapsto -q$, $y\mapsto -p$, respectively.

Comment: Very nice, @HagenvonEitzen . I'd make that an answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, it isn't completely. It merely restricts the words $x,y$ can map to in the other group very much. I *think* this can be extended to a proof, but am not through with that yet

Comment: My idea to look at abelianization isn't going to work, because the abelianization of this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ for any coprime pair $p,q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G = G_{pq} = \langle x,y \mid x^p=y^q \rangle$, with $p \le q$. Then $Z := Z(G)$ is the infinite cyclic group generated by $x^p$, and $G/Z$ is the free product of cyclic groups of orders $p$ and $q$, so its abelianization is $C_p \times C_q$.

One of the standard properties of free products $A*B$ is that any element of finite order is contained in a conjugate of $A$ or $B$. So the maximum finite order of an element of $G/Z$ is $q$.

Now if $G_{pq} \cong G_{p'q'}$ with $p \le q$ and $p' \le q'$, then $pq = p'q'$ from the abelianizations of $G/Z$, and $q=q'$ from maximum finite orders of elements in $G/Z$, and hence $p=p'$.

You don't need the comprimeness asumption.